# Heartbeat pattern using reactive extension

Tags: c#, system.reactive, .net-4.6, .net-4.6.1

Given a simple scenario:

A and B are in a room, A talks to B. The room is dark and B couldn't see A. How could B figure out if A is pausing or A is kidnapped from the room?

When A talks, A provides IObservable *Talk* that B subsequently subscribes to Talk.Subscribe(string=>process what A said). B could at the same time subscribe to Observable.Interval *Heartbeat* as a heartbeat checking.

My question is what Operator I should use to merge/combine two IObservable so that if there is no item from *Talk* over two items of *Heartbeat*, B will assume the A has been kidnapped.

Please note that I want to avoid a variable to store the state because it may cause the side effect if I don't synchronize that variable properly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a state variable you want to act on, with the state representing the number of heartbeats since 'A' last spoke. That would look like this:

```
var stateObservable = Observable.Merge(                     //State represent number of heartbeats since A last spoke
    aSource.Select(_ => new Func<int, int>(i => 0)),        //When a talks, set state to 0
    bHeartbeat.Select(_ => new Func<int, int>(i => i + 1))  //when b heartbeats, increment state
)
    .Scan(0, (state, func) => func(state));
```

We represent incidents of A speaking as a function resetting the state to 0, and incidents of B heartbeatting as incrementing the state. We then accumulate with the `Scan` function.

The rest is now easy:

```
var isKidnapped = stateObservable
    .Where(state => state >= 2)
    .Take(1);

isKidnapped.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("A is kidnapped"));
```

---

**EDIT**:

Here's an example with *n* A sources:

```
var aSources = new Subject<Tuple<string, Subject<string>>>();
var bHeartbeat = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Publish().RefCount();

var stateObservable = aSources.SelectMany(t =>
        Observable.Merge(
            t.Item2.Select(_ => new Func<int, int>(i => 0)),
            bHeartbeat.Select(_ => new Func<int, int>(i => i + 1))
        )
        .Scan(0, (state, func) => func(state))
        .Where(state => state >= 2)
        .Take(1)
        .Select(_ => t.Item1)
    );

stateObservable.Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine($"{s} is kidnapped"));
aSources
    .SelectMany(t => t.Item2.Select(s => Tuple.Create(t.Item1, s)))
    .Subscribe(t => Console.WriteLine($"{t.Item1} says '{t.Item2}'"));
bHeartbeat.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("**Heartbeat**"));

var a = new Subject<string>();
var c = new Subject<string>();
var d = new Subject<string>();
var e = new Subject<string>();
var f = new Subject<string>();

aSources.OnNext(Tuple.Create("A", a));
aSources.OnNext(Tuple.Create("C", c));
aSources.OnNext(Tuple.Create("D", d));
aSources.OnNext(Tuple.Create("E", e));
aSources.OnNext(Tuple.Create("F", f));

a.OnNext("Hello");
c.OnNext("My name is C");
d.OnNext("D is for Dog");
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1200));
e.OnNext("Easy-E here");
a.OnNext("A is for Apple");
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2200));
```

Comment: Thanks @Shlomo for your answer, is there any ways to scale this solution to n+1 where n is the number of talkers that can only be determined at run time?

Comment: Most likely. Could you define the problem better?

Comment: Currently, there is only A and B, I would like to see if the same solution can apply to C,D,E,F when the acts like A's role. The solution I could think of so far is having a list of IObservable and a list of subscriptions that will be added at run-time. Is there any more elegant way?

Comment: I code-dumped a solution with multiple. If you want more than that, you'll have to show me what you have.